# Can't install Ruby 2.0.0 using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby version 2.0.0 using RVM. I'm trying to use the Rails installer (railsinstaller.org).

I have downloaded the package and ran the installer and I have also restarted all terminal windows.

Here is the issue I am encountering:

[my terminal http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/9704/stacks.png](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/9704/stacks.png)

As you can see, it says that RVM installed Ruby version 2.0.0. When I try to tell RVM to use this version it says that it is not installed.

Comment: Your screenshot is not displaying.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the link. I was experimenting with another image host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it may have been fixed.  Try `rvm get head` and then try again: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1832

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Now I can continue on my journey through your book ;).